# random variable equals to $\infty$ a.s

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Assume that $P(X_n \to \infty) > 0$. Prove that $P(X_0 = \infty) = 1$. Hint: first prove that $P(X_n \to \infty) = 1$.

---

by 0-1 law we can conclude directly $P(X_n \to \infty) = 1$ but how to proceed?

Comment: what is meant by $P(X_n \to \infty)$ ???

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Potentially, $$\mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Borel-Cantalli Lemma $\sum P(X_n \leq M) =\sum P(X_0 \leq M)=\infty$ would imply that $P(X_n \leq M \,\, \text {i.o.})=1$, a contradiction. Hence, $\sum P(X_0 \leq M)<\infty$ which means $P(X_0 \leq M)=0$ for each $M$.

Comment: Why this is donwvoted? I don't understand

Comment: One never knows. Some people seem to downvote for the fun of it. @Hamilton